# nodejs - how to print object property value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to log `Socket.conn.socket.clientsCount`. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is the`console.log(socket)` output. I'm interested in printing only `clientsCount` using `console.log`.

```
Socket {
  nsp:
   Namespace {
     name: '/',
      ...
      ...
      ...
  conn:
   Socket {
     id: 'aklslasdalj-AAAA',
     server:
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
```

Comment: It should be `Socket.conn.server.clientsCount` because there is no `socket` property.

Comment: well I get undefined.  Note that `socket` is passed into a function. And in that function i tried `socket.Socket.conn.Server.clientsCounts` and I also tried `Socket.conn.Server.clientCounts`. First attempt - Cannot read property 'conn' of undefined. Second attempt - Socket is not defined

Comment: It should be `server` with a lowercase `s`, JavaScript is case sensitive. Also, there is no `socket` or `Socket`, it should be just `variableName.conn.server.clientsCount`

Comment: All the text that appears in light blue in the code indicates the object's type, those are not property names, so, the top level object is a `Socket` instance that has a `nsp` property and this property's value is an instance of `Namespace` and so on...

Comment: Thanks. `socket.conn.server.clientsCount` worked. Can you reply as answer? I'll accept it

Comment: Also a bit of explanation in your answer would be nice. Like if I want to display the `Server` Object under conn, would it be `socket.conn.Server`? don't think so...

Comment: I don't think an answer is necessary, this has to do with how the object is printed (represented in text) not with the format of the object itself. For accessing the `Server` instance, you'll need `socket.conn.server` (with a lowercase `s`).